# Email IDNA encoding. Do we need to encode the whole email or each parts separately?

Tags: email

I have an email with accents that needs to be encoded using IDNA (from Python)

Something like this:

> CäciliaAbitz@somedomain.net

If I do a `encode('idna')` for the whole email, I get the following:

> xn--cciliaabitz@somedomain-04b.net

The domains became **somedomain-04b.net**, which is not normal (right?)

Doing a encoding on each part of the email results in :

```
b''.join([x.encode('idna') for x in email.split('@')])
> b'xn--cciliaabitz-l8a@somedomain.net'
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct, working or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 5890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5890#section-2.3) works on labels, which are mostly dot separated parts of an email address. In your example, you only have one label in the local part (before the @ sign), "CäciliaAbitz", and two labels in the domain part ("somedomain.net"). If you encode without paying attention to the labels, you encode the dots, and the result is a single label where you need multiple ones. With that, your assumption, that "somedomain-04b.net" is not normal (or valid), is correct.

To correctly encode, you need to split not only between local and domain part at the @, but also at any dot within both local and domain parts.

Comment: Thank you Robert. So in the case of something like Cäcilia.Abitz@somedomain.net, I need to encode `Cäcilia`, `Abitz` `somedomain` and `net` separately, then merge them with either `@` and `.` like it was before?

Comment: @CyrilN. Yes, exactly.